# Writing an open source component with hooks results in Invalid hook call when using it after transpilation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, react-hooks

I'm writing a react component which I plan to open source.
For that I have this component inside a repository and transpile it with babel. I'm using hooks here.

A small excerpt of that component would be:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const MyComponent = props => {
  const index = useRef(0);

  // ...

  return (
    <RenderStuff />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I transpile it via babel with that `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

When I try to use that Component inside an example create-react-app project I get an error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>   See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I checked it all, I have `react` and `react-dom` only as a `peerDependency` of my component and I only get one version when I run `npm ls react react-dom` inside the example project.
I'm pretty confident that the hooks inside the component aren't really the problem, before I had this component inside an example project and it worked there, the only difference is now that I have it inside an own project.

When I remove the everything and just write a function component which renders a headline hello world I can use it, so I think the reason are the hooks.

The transpiled code looks like this:

```
var MyComponent = function MyCompontn(_ref) {
  var index = (0, _react.useRef)(0);
  // ...
 }
```

Could the error be there?
What are my options to fix this?

Comment: Does the JSX-transpiling work as expected?

Comment: Yep, with an `h1` as component content it is working as expected.

Comment: Same thing happens with my npm package. Did you manage to find a way to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was a `npm link` error somehow. I've published the package and everything worked as expected. But what I didn't understand: after that I've removed the dependency from the published packaged and linked it again with `npm link` and it worked. So I didn't have a full answer here yet.